# Json array to C# class

Tags: c#, json

I’ve got a very simple scenario.
I have an api response that simply returns an array of strings.

```
[‘test’,’test2’,’test3’]
```

I need to deserialise into an object to integrate with some current code.

I’ve tried using a straight class with a single property of type List but no dice.

How to deserialise into single object?

Comment: Dude ...!  https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeObject.htm

Comment: or the microsoft docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/how-to?pivots=dotnet-7-0#how-to-read-json-as-net-objects-deserialize

Comment: Just deserialise directly into `List<string>`, there's no need for a class.

Comment: I need to use a class as mentioned above

Comment: Skin - that is not the scenario I posted dude.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio, you can try to use the Paste special - Paste JSON as classes under the Edit menu. Otherwise you can use this simple tool https://json2csharp.com/.

For deserialize the json string, you can use this two extension method:

```
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Json;
     public static T DeserializeFromJsonString<T>(this string data)
        {
            using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data)))
                return stream.DeserializeFromJsonStream<T>();
        }
        public static T DeserializeFromJsonStream<T>(this Stream stream)
        {
            T result = (T)new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(T)).ReadObject(stream);
            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need deserialise the api outPut into single object:

```
    class _object
    {
        public List<string> value { get; set; }
        public _object(List<string> val)=>
            value = val;
    }

     string[] apiOutput =  { "test", "test2", "test3" };
     _object myobject = new _object(apiOutput.ToList());
```

If you want to convert the array into a list of objects:

```
    class _object
    {
        public string value { get; set; }
        public _object(string val)=>
            value = val;
    }

    string[] apiOutput = {"test", "test2", "test3"};
    List<_object> listObjest = apiOutput.Select(x => new _object(x)).ToList();
    listObjest.ForEach(x=>Console.WriteLine(x.value));
```